# orphanRemoval doesn't wok hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I've 2 hibernate JPA entities like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "[pembelian].[PO]")
public class PO implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;    
    private Date tglPO;
    private String keterangan;
    private String alamat;
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "po", orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<DetailPO> detailPOList;
}
```

The second one is

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "[pembelian].[DetailPO]")
public class DetailPO implements Serializable{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "PO_id")
    private PO po;

    private double qty;
    private BigDecimal harga = new BigDecimal(0); 
    private BigDecimal diskon = new BigDecimal(0);
    private BigDecimal pajak = new BigDecimal(0);
}
```

In my case, I have a PO with 3 list nodes DetailPO. Then, I delete a DetailPO node, so I only has 2 list nodes now. Afterthat I want to save the PO in the database. The data is saved successfully, but the DetailPO that I removed is not deleted in database.

Is there any error with my code?

Thank you before.

Comment: how did you remove? did you try po.getdetailPOList().remove(po)  then session.saveOrUpdate(po)

Comment: I did remove like this po.getdetailPOList().remove(detailPo) then session.save(po).

Comment: cn u try saveOrUpdate?

Comment: Yes, I tried. But I get the same result.

Comment: Can ypu post the code wheree you are doing that.. whole transaction block.

Comment: Try with session.merge(po) instead of session.update/saveOrUpdate/save(po), I dont know why but work for me.